# Wordpress cron jon every 6 hours

Tags: php, wordpress, cron-task

I currently have a Cron Job setup to run every hour. I actaully want to change it to run every 6 hours. I could not find a "sixhourly" setting. Am i missing something?

```
if (!wp_next_scheduled('retrySysProHook')) {
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'retrySysProHook');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/cron_schedules/

Allows you to set custom schedules.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179694/wp-schedule-event-every-day-at-specific-time

Has this example:

```
function myprefix_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_six_hours'] = array(
        'interval' => 21600, // Every 6 hours
        'display'  => __( 'Every 6 hours' ),
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myprefix_custom_cron_schedule' );
```

Comment: and do i replace "hourly" with "every_six_hours"

Comment: Why don't you try to modify the code, and see what happens, I suggest trying to make a 5 minute timer, and then you'll know it works.